# Skellam distribution with dummies - consistent ML estimates?

Tags: poisson-distribution, bias, poisson-regression, skellam-distribution

The difference of two Poisson distributed random variables follows a Skellam distribution.

We know that a Maximum Likelihood estimation using Poisson distribution yields consistent estimates also in presence of dummies (it does not suffer from the Nickell bias[1] as other non-linear models). Can we assume that for the Skellam distribution, this holds as well?

[1] Nickell, S. (1981),
"Biases in Dynamic Models with Fixed Effects"
*Econometrica*, **49** (6), 1417-1426

Comment: What is the "nickel bias"? A google search gives your question in position #2...